# DAX Code change suggestion

Tags: sql, ssas, dax

So I have this follwing DAX code for a Measure. What I am trying to do is replace the Billdetail[SOurceWasteServiceID] with another column ,BillDetail[SourceServiceMapID]. But the problem is that for a single SourceWasteServiceID, I can have multiple records for SourceServiceMapID. And since the data has to be grouped together, I cant just directly replace the one with other. This table does have an IsCurrent flag in the table, which is "1" for the latest record. I tried to use this IsCurrent in Filter statement but still I get mismatch data. 
 Anybody have any suggestions on how can I change this?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

```
 Sum of Volume:=CALCULATE(
                        SUMX(
                                     Summarize(BillDetail
                                                                ,BillDetail[SourceWasteServiceID]
                                                                ,BillDetail[ActualBillMonth]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[ContainerCount]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeQuantity]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[WastePickupSchedule]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[WastePickupFrequencyMultiplier]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[PercentFull]
                                                                ,WasteServiceMap[CompactionRatio]
                                                                ,"ItemQuantity", CALCULATE(Sum(BillDetail[ActualItemQuantity]),BillDetail[AlternateBillDetailKey] = True)
                                                                )
                                 ,IF ( UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WastePickupSchedule])) = "FIXED" 
                                            ,(WasteServiceMap[ContainerCount])
                                            * (WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeQuantity])  
                                            *(IF(WasteServiceMap[WastePickupFrequencyMultiplier] = -1,0,WasteServiceMap[WastePickupFrequencyMultiplier]))  
                                            * (WasteServiceMap[PercentFull]) 
                                            * (WasteServiceMap[CompactionRatio]) 
                                            *IF(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit])) = "GALLONS"
                                                    , 0.00495113169 
                                                    , IF(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit])) = "LITERS"
                                                            , 0.00130795062
                                                            ,IF(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit])) = "YARDS"  
                                                                    ,1
                                                                    ,BLANK())
                                                          )
                                                 )

                                            , IF ( OR(OR(OR(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WastePickupSchedule])) = "ON CALL" ,UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WastePickupSchedule])) = "MAILBACK"),UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WastePickupSchedule])) = "HAND PICKUP"),UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WastePickupSchedule])) = "SCHEDULED ONCALL")
                                                    , (WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeQuantity])  
                                                        * (WasteServiceMap[CompactionRatio]) 
                                                        * (WasteServiceMap[PercentFull]) 
                                                        * ([ItemQuantity])
                                                        *IF(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit])) = "GALLONS"
                                                            , 0.00495113169 
                                                            , IF(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit])) = "LITERS"
                                                                    , 0.00130795062
                                                                    ,IF(UPPER((WasteServiceMap[WasteContainerSizeUnit])) = "YARDS"  
                                                                            ,1
                                                                            ,BLANK())
                                                                  )
                                                         )
                                                    , 0
                                                )
                                    )

                            )
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You know... example you provided does not look like just a problem related to joining latest records to some "base" records, but... if it IS related despite all that, we can "play" with this problem a little bit. Just for fun.

Let's say we have two very simple tables in our database

```
create table parent_table
(
    parent_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    some_value nvarchar(100)
);

create table child_table
(
    child_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    parent_id int,
    is_current bit,
    some_value nvarchar(100)
);
```

with some meaningless, but related data

```
insert into parent_table (some_value) 
values ('value 1'),('value 2'),('value 3'),('value 4');

insert into child_table (parent_id, is_current, some_value) values 
(1, 1, 'value 1.1'),
(2, 0, 'value 2.1'),
(2, 0, 'value 2.2'),
(2, 1, 'value 2.3'),
(3, 0, 'value 3.1'),
(3, 1, 'value 3.2'),
(4, 0, 'value 4.1'),
(4, 1, 'value 4.2');
```

And... we want to find only current child data for every parent row.
If we wrote a query on T-SQL it could look as something like this

```
select p.parent_id
, p.some_value [parent_value]
, c.some_value [current_child_value]
from parent_table p
left join child_table c on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
    and c.is_current = 1;



(4 row(s) affected)

parent_id   parent_value    current_child_value
-----------------------------------------------
1           value 1         value 1.1
2           value 2         value 2.3
3           value 3         value 3.2
4           value 4         value 4.2
```

Now we could try to build some simple tabular model on top on these tables
[image]

and write a DAX query against it

```
evaluate
filter (
    addcolumns(
        child_table,
        "parent_value", related(parent_table[some_value])
    ),
    child_table[is_current] = True
)
```

having received almost the same results as using T-SQL

```
child_table[child_id]   child_table[parent_id]  child_table[is_current] child_table[some_value] [parent_value]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8                       4                       True                    value 4.2               value 4
6                       3                       True                    value 3.2               value 3
4                       2                       True                    value 2.3               value 2
1                       1                       True                    value 1.1               value 1
```

I hope it's helpful enough for you to solve your problem or at least it can point you to the right direction

Comment: In this case you are assuming that there is only one child id corresponding to the parent id but this is not the case. There are multiple child id for a single parent id. And the problem is that under the current logic of the code, the parent id is being grouped(SUMX clause). I tried to replace this parent id with the child id and then added a filter in ISCurrent= 1 but still i get different result set.

Comment: you have misunderstood my assumption. There are multiple child ids for a single parent id. So, please, check my answer again. And... why it's necessary to use grouping function if you have "IsCurrent" flag identifying the current child record? Solution I provided filters single child record for each parent record based on "IsCurrent" flag, so no grouping is needed.